# How to get UTC Offset during DST time in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc, dst

I am trying to get all offsets seen in a timezone, in an interval. Below is the function that I used to accomplish this, I know you could use `TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset` to get the `UTC offset` for a timezone during standard time, but there is no similar method to get one during daylight saving time unless you pass a particular `DST` point of time to the `GetUTCOffset()` method.

```
static void GetOffsets(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, TimeZoneInfo tz)
{
    var result = new HashSet<int>();
    var adjRules = tz.GetAdjustmentRules();
    result.Add(tz.BaseUtcOffset);

    foreach (var adjustmentRule in adjRules)
    {
        if ((startTime >= adjustmentRule.DateStart && startTime <= adjustmentRule.DateEnd) || (endTime >= adjustmentRule.DateStart && endTime <= adjustmentRule.DateEnd) ||
             (stTime <= adjustmentRule.DateStart && endTime >= adjustmentRule.DateEnd))
        {
            if(adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta != TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                if (!result.Contains(tz.BaseUtcOffset + adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta))
                      result.Add((tz.BaseUtcOffset + adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta));
            }
         }
     }

     foreach (var res in result)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(res);
     }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: The code is mysterious.  If you want all possible offsets then simply remove the tests on startTime and endTime.  How the result could be useful is very hard to see.

Comment: Hi Hans, Considering the fact that Microsoft has Rules that determines the DaylightDelta, I assumed that for this method to be generic I had to consider an interval or use DateTime.Min and DateTime.Max as intervals to get all past offSets seen.

Comment: use case: I use this offSet information to pass to a sql server db stored procedure, UI that drives a report has a dropdown that lists all 24 "1 hr: timeintervals in a day (ex 1PM -2PM), I convert this to an offSet to pass to a stored proc that had dateTime saved in UTC. if not for this use case, I am still trying to know if there is other way to solve my original question.

Comment: NB to check if two time periods overlap at all, you can use `p1.Start < p2.End && p2.Start < p1.End`. Use `<=` to taste.

Comment: Very valid question.  99% of the time you'll have two offsets: standard and daylight savings.  I'm needing the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

> I am trying to get all offsets seen in a timezone, in an interval.

I would *strongly* advise you to avoid trying to use `TimeZoneInfo` directly. The adjustment rules can be surprisingly awkward for some zones in some years, as I've found to my expense.

While I'm biased, I'd suggest using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), which can wrap a `TimeZoneInfo` and do the hard work for you, via `BclDateTimeZone.FromTimeZoneInfo`. Your question isn't entirely clear in terms of requirements, but if you can say a bit more about what you're trying to do, I can write the appropriate Noda Time code for you.

Your initial description could be implemented with something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ZoneInterval> GetZoneIntervalsInInterval
    (this DateTimeZone zone, Interval interval)
{
    Instant current = interval.Start;
    while (current < interval.End && current != Instant.MaxValue)
    {
        ZoneInterval zi = zone.GetZoneInterval(current);
        yield return zi;
        current = zi.End;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var zone = BclDateTimeZone.FromTimeZoneInfo(tzInfo);
var offsets = zone.GetZoneIntervalsInInterval(interval)
                  .Select(zi => zi.WallOffset)
                  .Distinct();
```

That's assuming that you mean the same thing by "offset" as I do (namely the difference between UTC and local time).

Comment: Thanks for the help! @Jon. Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of adding third party libraries at this stage of project while we are 3 weeks away from dev release, I have to rely on .NET bcl methods for now, like I mentioned in my question, my requirement is to filter historical data where datetime's are in UTC in sql server with time filters like '8am -9am'. The timezone that was originally used for conversion is provided in the configuration, so given a timezone I need to know the offSets it has seen so I could use this information to filter historic data in database.

Comment: I was able to get this working with my post in "answers", atleast it's working for currentzon'es of interest(EST, CST, PST, GBT), you mentioned that Adjustment rules are awkward for somezones in some years. when did you think the information from Timezoneinfo was awkward, What does your wrapper rely on when you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

I did comeup with this method to get the offSets needed to be considered for a UTC interval within a year interval for a specified timezoneinfo. I pass this collection to database to filter datetime fields saved in UTC for interval filter inputs like ("1am - 2am"), I did test this for all Timezones in my system and it worked fine. Although this is not a answer to my original question as I am still using Adjustment rules to get the offSets, I tried to make it usable this time.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
        {
            var result = GetUTCOffsetsByUTCIntervals(1900, 2012, tz);
            Console.WriteLine(tz.DisplayName);
            foreach (var tuple in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1 + "     " + tuple.Item2 + "   " + tuple.Item3);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static List<Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>> GetUTCOffsetsByUTCIntervals(int stYear, int endYear, TimeZoneInfo tz)
    {
        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        var offsetsByUTCIntervals = new List<Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>>();
        var adjRules = tz.GetAdjustmentRules();
        for (var year = stYear; year <= endYear && year < DateTime.MaxValue.Year && year >= DateTime.MinValue.Year; year++)
        {
            var adjRule =
                adjRules.FirstOrDefault(
                    rule =>
                    rule.DateStart.Year == year || rule.DateEnd.Year == year ||
                    (rule.DateStart.Year < year && rule.DateEnd.Year > year));

            var yrStTime = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
            var yrEndTime = yrStTime.AddYears(1).AddTicks(-1);

            if (adjRule != null)
            {
                var tStDate = GetTransitionDate(adjRule.DaylightTransitionStart, year);
                var tEnddate = GetTransitionDate(adjRule.DaylightTransitionEnd, year);

                var stTsp = adjRule.DaylightTransitionStart.TimeOfDay.TimeOfDay;

                var endTsp = adjRule.DaylightTransitionEnd.TimeOfDay.TimeOfDay;

                if (yrStTime.Date == tStDate && yrStTime.TimeOfDay == stTsp)
                    yrStTime = yrStTime.Add(adjRule.DaylightDelta);

                if (yrEndTime.Date == tEnddate && yrEndTime.TimeOfDay == endTsp)
                    yrEndTime = yrEndTime.Subtract(adjRule.DaylightDelta);

              if (tStDate.Month > tEnddate.Month)
                {
                    offsetsByUTCIntervals.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>(tz.BaseUtcOffset + adjRule.DaylightDelta, ConvertTimeToUtc(yrStTime, tz), ConvertTimeToUtc(tEnddate.AddTicks(endTsp.Ticks - 1), tz)));
                    offsetsByUTCIntervals.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>(tz.BaseUtcOffset, ConvertTimeToUtc(tEnddate.Add(endTsp.Subtract(adjRule.DaylightDelta)), tz), ConvertTimeToUtc(tStDate.AddTicks(stTsp.Ticks - 1), tz)));
                    offsetsByUTCIntervals.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>(tz.BaseUtcOffset + adjRule.DaylightDelta, ConvertTimeToUtc(tStDate.Add(stTsp.Add(adjRule.DaylightDelta)), tz), ConvertTimeToUtc(yrEndTime, tz))); 
                }
                else
                {
                    offsetsByUTCIntervals.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>(tz.BaseUtcOffset, ConvertTimeToUtc(yrStTime, tz), ConvertTimeToUtc(tStDate.AddTicks(stTsp.Ticks - 1), tz)));
                    offsetsByUTCIntervals.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>(tz.BaseUtcOffset + adjRule.DaylightDelta, ConvertTimeToUtc(tStDate.Add(stTsp.Add(adjRule.DaylightDelta)), tz), ConvertTimeToUtc(tEnddate.AddTicks(endTsp.Ticks - 1), tz)));
                    offsetsByUTCIntervals.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>(tz.BaseUtcOffset, ConvertTimeToUtc(tEnddate.Add(endTsp.Subtract(adjRule.DaylightDelta)), tz), ConvertTimeToUtc(yrEndTime, tz))); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                offsetsByUTCIntervals.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, DateTime, DateTime>(tz.BaseUtcOffset, ConvertTimeToUtc(yrStTime, tz), ConvertTimeToUtc(yrEndTime, tz)));
            }
        }
        return offsetsByUTCIntervals;
    }

    public static DateTime ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime date, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        if (date == null || timeZone == null)
        {
            return date;
        }
        DateTime convertedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, timeZone);
        return convertedDate;
    }

    //copy from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.transitiontime.isfixeddaterule.aspx
    private static DateTime GetTransitionDate(TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transition, int year)
    {
        if (transition.IsFixedDateRule)
            return new DateTime(year, transition.Month, transition.Day);

        int transitionDay;
        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        var startOfWeek = transition.Week * 7 - 6;
        var firstDayOfWeek = (int)cal.GetDayOfWeek(new DateTime(year, transition.Month, 1));
        var changeDayOfWeek = (int)transition.DayOfWeek;

        if (firstDayOfWeek <= changeDayOfWeek)
            transitionDay = startOfWeek + (changeDayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek);
        else
            transitionDay = startOfWeek + (7 - firstDayOfWeek + changeDayOfWeek);

        if (transitionDay > cal.GetDaysInMonth(year, transition.Month))
            transitionDay -= 7;
        return new DateTime(year, transition.Month, transitionDay);
    }

   /* static void GetOffsets(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, TimeZoneInfo tz)
    {
        var result = new HashSet<string>();
        var adjRules = tz.GetAdjustmentRules();
        result.Add(tz.BaseUtcOffset.ToString());

        foreach (var adjustmentRule in adjRules)
        {
            if ((startTime >= adjustmentRule.DateStart && startTime <= adjustmentRule.DateEnd)
                    || (endTime >= adjustmentRule.DateStart && endTime <= adjustmentRule.DateEnd)
                 || (startTime <= adjustmentRule.DateStart && endTime >= adjustmentRule.DateEnd))
            {
                if(adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta != TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    if (!result.Contains((tz.BaseUtcOffset + adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta).ToString()))
                      result.Add((tz.BaseUtcOffset + adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write(tz.DisplayName + "   ");
        foreach (var res in result)
        {
            Console.Write(res);
        }
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing anything complex with dates you should take a look at [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) (which is a port of the Joda Time Java library). It has a whole namespace for dealing with thorny time zone issues.